# django error: 'subjects' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working in my first django project. Unfortunately, I'm facing an issue that should be straightforward. my scenario:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

## 1. Model for user registration

class subjects(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __Str__(self):
        return self.description
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login , authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect 
from poc_teaching.models import subjects

# Create your views here.


def list_subj(request): 
    subj = subjects.objects.all()

    return render (request,'subjects.html',{'subjects': subj})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
#from . import views
from poc_teaching import views as poc_views


urlpatterns = [

    url('subjects/$',poc_views.subjects,name ='subjects'),

]
```

**html**

```
<head>
"hello world"
</head>
<div>
{{ subjects }}
</div>
```

I'm getting the error: `'subjects' object has no attribute 'get'`

I've gone thru the admin console to add objects. So, I'm pretty sure I should get results. I have gone thru many documents but really I dont understand where is my issue. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the wrong view. Your `urlpattern` should call the view `list_subj`.

Change your `urlpatterns` to this -

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^subjects/$',poc_views.list_subj,name ='subjects'),
]
```